# 'IWebJobsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddAzureStorageCoreServices' 'AddTimers'

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Missing references upgrading to Webjob V3

Installed the references

'IWebJobsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddTimers' and no accessible extension method 'AddTimers' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebJobsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 18):

For .net 6.0 , for `"AddAzureStorageCoreServices"` extension method you have to add **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage**
instead of **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions**

For `AddAzureStorage` , in .net 6.0 it's not supported anymore you have to replace it with `AddAzureStorageBlobs` or `AddAzureStorageQueuesextention` method you need to add Nuget package: **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage**

Answer (score 5):

Using NuGet package Manager, install **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions** and **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage** packages.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove the references
clean the project 
delete bin and obj folder 
add the references again

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions version > 3 you will get this error also, drop it to the last 3.xxx version and should work.